# Rackstore and rackpick multiple agents at a time in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to develop a model that essentially shows the movement of material in the warehouse.

I want the rackstore block to move multiple boxes at a time in the rack using crane. In the current model, crane takes one box at a time, stores it in the rack and comes back to take next box.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if RackStore supports that, but as always, you can find a solution in AnyLogic.

One simple fix: bundle your packages together into 1 agent using the batch object. Then, they stay together until being taken out by the crane at the end (via RackPick) and you can un-batch them to their original agents. Have a look at some example models using batching.

cheers

Comment: Thank you. When using the batch and un-batch, can we un-batch the agents while they are in the rack? If I try so, I get an error ' agent is not present in the rack' while picking them up. Batch of agents that is being stored and picked up may not be the same for my project. Also, what is the difference between pickup and batch?

Comment: you cannot, as far as I know. Re the difference, please refer to the AnyLogic help and its example models on both objects, they explain it well.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the details of your model, one option is to use batch as Benjamin stated, but I think I feel the pickup dropoff blocks would work better because with the dropoff you can drop the boxes one by one, while the batch forces you to separate all the boxes at once...

So with the rackstore you can't do this, but if you use the pickup and then dropoff, you will have to store somewhere in your model what rack positions are free though, because when you move the crane you will have to choose the rack position yourself, while the rackstore does it automatically...

Nevertheless, the batch may also work... it depends on the details of your model